# How to show a picture?

Tags: android, image

I'm having a problem calling a picture to view.  In my app after they click the button i want to take them to a new page where it will display a picture and under it some text.  For this example say i want a pic if dog to be at the top of the page then under it say i want something like the breed and the cost of breed. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Use this XML for your page what will display the image:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="src"
/>
<TextView
    android:text="image text"
    android:layout_below ="@id/image"
 />
```

Of course, add more options to the views

Some good references:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Also for other questions like this, I highly recommend reading the [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) section of the online Android [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Comment: I read those often the only problem is I'm more a visual person reading the text doesn't do much for me unless they have something i can look at and say "Oh I see what they are saying here."

Answer (score 0):

In a layout XML, put a LinearLayout, oriented vertically, containing first an ImageView widget then a TextView widget. You can set the text using TextView#setText(String) and the image using ImageView#setDrawable(...).

This layout will be used by an activity that reads the Extra information (for example the text to show and the image URL or the image path on the SDCard) when it starts.

You should read more about Views on the Android developer's guide as advised by Shawn Lauzon.

Answer (score -1):

write the above code in your .xml

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scaleType="center">
</ImageView>
```

and add this line in your .java class

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```